# Nativescript 6.1 returns an error when adding custom css file to the page

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've just updated my app to Nativescript 6.1 but I'm having this error calling `page.addCss`:

```
page.addCssFile('~/themes/' + settings.cssThemeName + '.css');
```

and I'm not getting this error:

```
Error: Could not load CSS from ~/themes/white.css: Error: require's first parameter should be string
```

Could it be a bug? I've tried multiple way to reach the file but I'm always getting the same error

Comment: What's the `require` line in your css file look like?

Comment: @IanMacDonald There is no require inside the css file, it's just simple css

Comment: Without a require statement webpack may not include the CSS file in the bundle. You will have to adjust the webpack config to include the file in your bundle.

Comment: Have you updated the webpack plugin and its configs to latest?

Comment: @Manoj the file is included by webpack, it works with Nativescript 6.0

Comment: @MartinYankov Yes I've created a new project with NS 6.1 and copied the dependencies versions to my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue after I upgraded some of the packages.

upgrade all components to the latest version and everything it should be fine.

This is what I currently have and it's working perfectly.

√ Component nativescript has 6.1.0 version and is up to date.

√ Component tns-core-modules has 6.1.0 version and is up to date.

√ Component tns-android has 6.1.0 version and is up to date.

"nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.2.0",

Don't forget to regenerate the webpack configuration and dependencies with

npm i nativescript-dev-webpack@latest --save-dev ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs

For more details here is the documentation [Nativescript Upgrade Instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions)